# RSpec: Can I retain the new Rspec (2.0.x) with the old one (1.3.x) and still run autospec on 2.3.x Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I gave Rails3 a try and to do so I installed the new gems, like RSpec2. When I went back to my old apps though, autospec stopped working for Rails 2.3.x apps:

```
$ AUTOFEATURE=true autospec
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable autospec for rspec-2.0.1 (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/bin/autospec:19
```

When searching for this error on Google all I find are solutions that are for Rails 3. Based on what I've read, it seems that autospec executable has changed/removed.

Is there a way I can keep the new RSpec gems and still use autospec in 2.3.x apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the exact same problem, and i solved this by using rvm and gemsets. I described that in [this article](http://www.dixis.com/?p=414).